# Python decode "\u041b" string

Tags: python, unicode

I have unicode string, i'm sure that it's UTF-8, but I can't decode it. The string is `'\u041b\u0435\u0433\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435'`. How to decode it?

Comment: decode to what - how do you want to use it?

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb :) print u'\u0441\u0438\u0434\u0435\u043d\u044c\u044f' gives normal Human-readable string.

Comment: It is definitely not UTF8.

Comment: @glglgl, which encoding can it be?

Comment: @RankoR None at all - it is just Unicode. `\u` serves to escape a unicode codepoint within unicode strings (`u''` in 2.x, `''` in 3.x). If they occur within a string (2.x) resp. bytes object (3.x), they can be decoded as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `aString.decode('unicode_escape')`, it convert a unicode-format string to unicode object

```
>>> u'\u041b\u0435\u0433\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435'
u'\u041b\u0435\u0433\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435'
>>> '\u041b\u0435\u0433\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435'.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u041b\u0435\u0433\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435'
>>>
```

In your case

```
>>> print '\u041b\u0435\u0433\u043a\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0435'.decode('unicode_escape')
Легковые
>>>
```